# AndroidStudio onCheackedChangeListener

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I want to learn how to use the listener `onCheckedChangeListener`, but every time I implement it, the app is closed. I know it can be done with `onCLick`, but I need to know how to use this:

```
package com.example.tonij.colores;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CheckBox rojo,verde,azul;
    Button ponerColor, borrar;
TextView texto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rojo= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.botonRojo);
        verde= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.botonVerde);
        azul= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.botonAzul);

        rojo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked==true){
                            texto.setText("enga");
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

        ponerColor= (Button) findViewById(R.id.ponerColor);
        borrar= (Button) findViewById(R.id.borrar);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want but you haven't initialized your `textTo` TextView and it is sure to crash. Also change `if(isChecked==true)` to `if(isChecked)`. it's cringy

Comment: Okey, thanks, but i think that it isn't the problem, when i use the code it return to me a null point exception -->  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring those widgets before `onCreate()` method perhaps that causes the issue. However, you never initialized the `TextView` (`texto`) too.

So try this:

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextviewid);
        ponerColor= (Button) findViewById(R.id.ponerColor);
        borrar= (Button) findViewById(R.id.borrar);
        rojo= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.botonRojo);
        verde= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.botonVerde);
        azul= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.botonAzul);

        rojo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked){
                            texto.setText("enga");
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method
Navigate to “Developer options”, ensure “USB debugging” is enabled, then enable “Bug report shortcut”.  Capture bug report by holding the power button and selecting the “Take bug report” option.